# listview setItemChecked doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

For some reason setItemChecked doesn't work. can some one help me fix ti ?

```
String[] str = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.brush_type);
sizeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), R.layout.drawing_list_item, str);

listType = SIZE_LIST;
listView.setAdapter(sizeArrayAdapter);

// Populate the listView
listView.setItemChecked(4,true);
```

and this is the list item:

```
<CheckedTextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawingCheckedTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:background="@drawable/list_panel"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"/>
```

please help me.

Comment: You have to implement Checkable Interface too. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19997650/1361494

Comment: `CheckedTextView` already implements it, as stated here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html `An extension to TextView that supports the Checkable interface.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) say this:

> Sets the checked state of the
>   specified position. The is only valid
>   if the choice mode has been set to
>   CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or
>   CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.

So you might try:

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

before calling `setItemChecked`.

Comment: I naively thought using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice would take care of this, but I guess as I'm learning it should be obvious that setting the layout doesn't set the actual behavior at all?