# Hightlight the first row from the listview

Tags: android

My requirement is highlight first row form list when the activity load(initial listview should be highlighted.).

I have done like this

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sales_routes);

    ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
    ArrayList<String> routhPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
        routhPath.add(((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_two_column, R.id.FROM_CELL, routhPath));
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setSelected(true);
    list.setSelection(0);
    list.getItemAtPosition(0);
    System.out.println(" ========= "  +  list.getItemAtPosition(0));
    list.setFocusable(true);
    list.requestFocus();
```

This is not selected that particular row.

I have to select first row as well as select the radio button also.

[image]
Please help me.

please help me this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
requestFocus() method;
```

`list.getChildAt(0).setSelection(true);` method may be `getChildAtPosition(0)`.See what is available.I am confused

Comment: My case "list.getItemAtPosition(0)" its return "Mt.Lavinia 1". Not select the radio button

Comment: it is the text of radio button.You have to set is as selected

Comment: try list.getItemAtPosition(0).toggle();

Comment: even either of condition not working.see this my code -  this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_two_column, R.id.FROM_CELL, routhPath));
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.requestFocus();
        list.setSelected(true);
        list.setSelection(0);
        list.setFocusable(true);. Is there any order for this?

Comment: try with list.getItemAtPosition(0).toggle();

Comment: View v=(RadioButton) list.getChildAt(0);v.toggle();

Comment: "list.getItemAtPosition(0)" its return "Mt.Lavinia 1" so may be wrong in the radiobutton xml part

Comment: try with childAt.it will give you object.print it to see whether it is string or RadioButton.You need to get the child as RadioButton so that you can toggle it

Comment: Thank Rasel for your help. I have selected checkbox. This link was help for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303502/listview-setitemchecked-doesnt-work