# The CheckedTextViews in my ListView tick and untick themselves

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter, checkedtextview, ischecked

I've spent the past 3 hours trying to make this work, so sorry if I forget to post something...

Here's the problem:

- I'm using a ListView, which has a custom BuddyArrayAdapter which inflates an XML containing a side-by-side image and a CheckedTextView. I want to have only one choice, so i set it up to use SINGLE_CHOICE.

(Pretend the ampersands are images and brackets are checkedtextview's checkbox.)

```
    //my list looks like this

    & name1Here          []

    & name2Here          []

    & name3Here          []

    & name4Here          []
```

I'll post code tomorrow, but here's what I've been experiencing. 
 - if i use getChildAt() in the listView's onItemClick(), random children check on and off, but after enough clicks all of them uncheck eventually.
 - if i implement checkedTextView.onClick() in the adapter's getView(), i get nullpointerexceptions for every row in the listview.
 - if I do anything else that makes sense, upon selecting a row, the checkbox ticks and immediately unticks itself as if i didn't click. But it's still "clicked" because i can get it with listView.getCheckedItemPosition()

I have looked through the code, and i'm not calling toggle() anywhere anymore. The only clickListener i have is in the list.

Basically, this is what it looks like now

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            listConversations.setItemChecked(position, true);
            Log.d("<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "listConversations.getCheckedItemPosition() = "+listConversations.getCheckedItemPosition());

            listConversations.


            OnContactClick(position, id);
        }
```

The number logged is correct. However even with this dumb approach the CheckedTextView's checkable part still ticks/unticks itself on one click. This was my last try for today since i expected the listview to tick off all the others, but no. Either i have way more than one, or none at all.

If you still don't understand the question - what did I mess up to earn this hell and not be able to make the checkmark work like it's supposed to?!?!

Please help. I wasted 3 hours on this ridiculously retarded thing. I am desperate.

lastminuteadd: looks like i'm having the same kind of issue as this guy 
[ListView: setItemChecked only works with standard ArrayAdapter - does NOT work when using customized ArrayAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369640/listview-setitemchecked-only-works-with-standard-arrayadapter-does-not-work-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because nobody answered I guess I'll have to...

The trick was to make a Wrapper class implement Checkable. And to make the wrapper class if one was missing...