# setItemChecked is not working in list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Following is the code where i have set the adapter for list

```
  ListView drawer;

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),             R.layout.drawer_item, list);
  drawer.setAdapter(adapter);
 // drawer.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

  drawer.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);
```

I have added  `drawer.setItemChecked(pos,true);` in `onItemClickListener`. But its not working.

Comment: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16990047/2811956) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369927/2811956) and [this also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303958/2811956) it may help you

Comment: I have tried these already but still it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
 drawer.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

do this after you are doing findviewbyid for your listview and when your checkbox is clicked in `setonclicklistner` and you can also use `checkedchangelistener`
inside it do this

```
   listOfSavedItems.setItemChecked(i, ((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
```

and you can use `SparseBooleanArray` to see wheather it is set or not like

```
  SparseBooleanArray sbA=listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

and use `setTag` and `getTag` for getting the positions of all checkbox and according to position it will check or uncheck the checkboxes

```
    for (int i = 0; i <=positionsSparseArray.size(); i++) {
        int pos = (int) viewHolder.checkBox.getTag();
        if (i == pos) {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(positionsSparseArray.get(i));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all items inside your list view to non focusable.

```
drawer.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Also, make sure that for items inside list item set focusable false

```
android:focusable="false"      
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used customized adapter having checkbox and name as seperate entities which were on tabitems i used `OnCheckedChangeListener`, its a lengthy process but worked for me.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflator = reportViewContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.tabitems, null);            
        viewHolder.name= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.address= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.adress);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        UserModel element = (UserModel) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
                        UserModel model= data.get(position);
                        model.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(data.get(position));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(data.get(position));
    }
      //remaining data operation tasks....
```

cheers!..